# Laravel Scheduled Command doesn't run

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel, I have a cron in `Kernel.php` that doesn't seem to run when just left to run, if I run `php artisan command-name` manually, it does work. Below is what I have in `Kernel.php`, I'm not sure what's stopping it running every 5 minutes, automatically:

```
$schedule->command('command-name')
->everyFiveMinutes()
->withoutOverlapping()
->runInBackground()
->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/command-name.log'));
```

Comment: you need to schedule a cron job on your server which will run 
`php artisan schedule:run` which will then invoke everything that is scheduled in your Kernel file.

Comment: I already have other commands in my Kernel file which are running though.

Comment: Might be a problem with the ->withoutOverlapping() method. I had a problem in my application with it, but couldn't figure out the cause. So I just deleted the line.

Answer (score 0):

withoutOverlapping should create a file in storage folder with a name as

```
schedule_123456....
```

If the command stopped abruptly this file could remain undeleted. I think you have to delete it manually.

Two things:

1. withoutOverlapping create a lock for 24 hours that avoids to run a new instance of same, while runInBackground let more than one instance to run concurrently. I'ld use only one of the two options..
2. you can pass a parameter to withoutOverlapping to let the check to last less than 24 hours